# Should I concat wll my .js files into one in an AngularJS WebApp?

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a WebApp, the whole project is based on `AngularJS` and `PHP` (as backend), I'm in the final part, giving it the final touches, tests, etc. I have a doubt in whether or not it is recommended to concat all my `.js` files into one. I'm asking this because i'm using a lot of code, that i wrote by self, as well as third part libraries, such as form masks, dialogs, angular material, etc..

I have 2 pages structures, a `dist` folder for the final minified `.js` files, and a `src` folder where i have everything in peaces.

```
src                                     dist
├── app                                 ├── js
│   ├── .app-ctrl.js                    │   ├── .app.min.js
│   ├── .app-dire.js                    │   ├── .angular.min.js
│   └── .app-fact.js                    │   └── .angular-animate.min.js
│   └── .app-main.js                    │   └── .angular-material.min.js
└── js                                  │   └── .[...etc...].min.js
│    ├── .angular.min.js                └── lib
│    ├── .angular-animate.min.js            ├── .ngDialog.min.js
│    └── .angular-material.min.js           ├── .ngMask.min.js
│    └── .[...etc...].min.js                └── .[...etc...].min.js
└── lib
    ├── .ngDialog.min.js
    ├── .ngMask.min.js
    └── .[...etc...].min.js
```

Then in my `html` file I'm loading each of these files, like so:

```
<!-- Main Scripts -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/angular-router.min.js"></script>
[..etc..]

<!-- Lib Scripts -->
<script src="dist/lib/ngMask.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/lib/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/lib/ngNotification.min.js"></script>
[...etc...]
```

My biggest doubt is about the concat of all of these files.

Is it recomended to do it?
Which files should i concat? Because i know angular is a big library, and shouldn't be concat with other ones (at least i wouldn't do it). But there are other ones, smaller ones.

Since I'm a new user in `AngularJs` (as well as in javascript, just based on what i've learned from `Angular`) what would be the benefits of doing so? Is it going to give a better performance? Better security of my code?

What should i do to make those things better?
These are important questions i'd like to know to make a better development and also a better acabamento code of my app.

---

#### Edit

I was reading more about this and i also found the option to `obfuscate` the code, in addition to make the code safer. I even found this [npm plugin grunt-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-obfuscator), but it's not working. As far as i know, it doesn't work with `AngularJS`. Is there another way to do it? To obfuscate the code or make it safer?

Comment: Use gulp to minify and concat your files for the production environment only.

Comment: @ODelibalta I'm already using grunt to make this process. But i don't know how far should i go to group all of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to make use of CDN, It is certainly recommended to concat if you have a single app. Angular dependencies would be useless without app scripts, and vice versa. It doesn't matter if they are core libraries, third-party libraries or your own code.

The main concern is loading speed (one big js file will be downloaded faster). You don't need to go any further than mere concatenation in this case, just follow the order in which js files are loaded. Do it with [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat), [Gulp](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat) or [any other tool](https://github.com/jalba/concat-cli).

The things become different if there are several sets of possibly loaded js files, and some of app parts depend on some other, but not all. In this case there should be several concatenated files. Manual concatenation is inefficient here, but module bundlers are, via bundles/chunks. [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle), [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles), [JSPM](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/wiki/Production-Workflows#creating-a-bundle) and [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) are all capable of that.

Comment: Ok, so you recommend to have one big js file with all the other codes, like `bigmain.min.js` instead of `angular.min.js`, `app.min.js`, `angular-route.min.js`etc.. ? Also, i was reading more about this, and i found the option to obfuscate the code. I tried it with my own code but it didn't worked. Does it work for `AngularJs`? Or just for plain `JavaScript`? Any tool for it (specially to be used with grunt)?

Comment: UglifyJS (and [Grunt plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) in particular). Sure, all third-party libraries support minification. You need to follow [the guidelines](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification) to make your app minification-friendly. If you concat by hand, it is more performance-wise to concat pre-minified files, e.g. `angular.min.js`. Module bundlers also support minification of course and can be integrated into Grunt.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already working with grunt ugilify to minify my files, in this part, everything is working fine. I just don't know what is `mangle` or how to obfuscate a angularjs file, with the plugin i tried, it didn't worked.

Comment: 'mangle' is the obfuscation in Uglify's slang. And you need to annotate injected services properly to minify the code, that's in the guidlines.